# Enable submit button on selecting an option along with checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

i have a javascript below which enables the submit button if check the checkbox(atlease one).
but i want to enable the submit button if i select at least on option in select box along with checkbox.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(function(){
        var checkboxes = $("input[name='cand[]']"),
        submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

        checkboxes.click(function () {
            submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
        });
    });//]]>  

</script>

<form>
    <select name="status">
         <option value="">Move To</option>
          <option value="shortlisted">Shortlisted</option>
          <option value="finalised">Finalised</option>
          <option value="rejected">Rejected</option>
    </select> 
    <input  name="cand[]" value="<? echo $cand_id ; ?> " type="checkbox"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Apply" disabled>
</form>
```

kindly help on this.

Comment: this is working fine with checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it, as long as your non-selected value is `""`.

```
$(function(){
    var checkboxes = $("input[name='cand[]']"),
        sel = $('select[name=status]'),
        submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

    function updateSubmitButtonState() {
        submitButt.prop("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked") || !sel.val());
    }

    checkboxes.click(updateSubmitButtonState);
    sel.change(updateSubmitButtonState);
});
```